# Javascript Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: javascript, webpack, jestjs

I am facing this error when launching my tests with Javascript. I am trying to build a game with Phaser 3, and I want to do the tests as I am writing code. It is the first time it appears and I have the same config as in other projects. The error is followed by `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. And some instructions to 'transform' to my config. But I do not have any file for jest config

my test:

```
import { getScore, setScore } from '../src/helpers/leaderboard';

describe('Should set and get score from the API', ()=>{
  it('should save the score into the API', ()=>{
    setScore('Dung', 50000).then(data => {
      expect(data.result).toBe('Leaderboard score created correctly.');
    });
  });
  it('should get the name of the player', async ()=>{
      const user = await getScore();
      expect(user.result.score).toEqual(50000);
    });
});
```

My file.js:

```
export const setScore = async (playerName = '', gameScore = 0) => {
  const info = {
    user: playerName,
    score: gameScore,
  };
  const settings = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(info)
  };
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, settings);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return e;
  }
}

export const getScore = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      mode: 'cors'
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data.result;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}
```

my package.json:

```
{  
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack/prod.js ",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/base.js --open"
  },
  "keywords": [],  
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.2.0",
    "raw-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.7",
    "webpack": "^4.44.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.2.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.0",
    "phaser": "^3.24.1",
    "phaser3-rex-plugins": "^1.1.21",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.7"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "jest-canvas-mock"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: How is your source structure look like? Also the jest config file?

Comment: I do no have jest config file

Comment: I suggest to use `babel-js` as a transformer in your case. From my understanding that jest can run esmodule perfectly though

Comment: Or if you're project in public, then share me then I can support you

Comment: This is  the github with all the code, branch feature => https://github.com/javitocor/Dung-Salvation-Shooter-Game-JS/   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found it. Babel 7 is not working with .babelrc, I had to delete it and add a babel.confij.js. Now it works!!!

Comment: Good to hear that. But I don't know why you don't configure anything at least using `babel-jest` to use babel to transform your tests so how babel can affect to your test. To be honest I'm still confused with your info :)

Comment: Just found this from official website “ Note: babel-jest is automatically installed when installing Jest and will automatically transform files if a babel configuration exists in your project. To avoid this behavior, you can explicitly reset the transform configuration option”